How should my new fan/light switch be connected?
I am trying to replace a panel for fan and light control.  I thought it would be as easy as matching the same colored wires but don't really know what I am doing. I am also unsure where to connect the ground wire. If anybody has any step by step instructions or suggestions, that would be much appreciated.  Thanks.




The black wire coming off the bundle of blacks (1) is your hot supply. That connects to the hot on your switch. In your poorly focused photo I'd guess that's black on your switch. Consult the literature.
If I'm correct about that point, red and blue on your new switch are the switched outputs. These can arbitrarily be connected to the red wire formerly connected to the switch (2) and the black wire from the same cable (3). These are supplies to the fan and light.
If your switch has a leg dedicated for motor (fan) use, make sure you use that correctly.
The green wire on the new switch is your ground. It'll need to be connected to the bare ground that passes under the screw at the back of the box. If there's a pigtail available, use a suitable wire nut or other connecter to tie them together. If not, detach it from the screw and add a two pigtails of suitable wire. Connect one to the screw on the box and one to the green wire on the switch. Do not attempt to put two wires under the screw.


The copper wire wrapped around the screw is a solid loop.  Do you mean to cut this wire and attach one end to the screw and the other to the green ground with pigtails?

Would it be better to get a screw and small bracket (like in the bottom) to attach to the empty hole in the top to put the new green ground.  Or do the grounds have to go together?

You can feasibly add a screw, but it needs to be of the specifically correct size and type and in a suitable hole. A wire nut is the shortest path to success.

Yeah, you can cut that passthrough loop and bundle them all with a wire nut.
